# How to Access the Xcode Verison Number like Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a) Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to Get the Xcode Verison Number like Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a) Programmatically in the App using OBJ-C or Swift  , As i have Requirement , where i need to Take that number and Display that in Application Settings ,Or is it even Possible  as I know Apple Do it when we use the iTunes Connect

Comment: I guess to piggyback off of Thomas' answer, is there a reason you need to be able to get that number programmatically versus just having it as a string that you change when you update Xcode? Are you just concerned about forgetting to do that or is someone requiring you do it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the contents of `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/version.plist`

You could create a project local file using awk by extracting the version string and add it to the bundle.

I guess you don't change XCode versions like your underwear. So simply create a text file with the version number and stow it somewhere. Then in the Targets settings open the Build Phases and include that file in Copy Bundle Resources. Now in your app you can read that file as it will be part of your bundle.

Comment: Can you Write Some Code Code how to Access it , as i am new to programming .

Comment: Nope. You need to do that yourself. See my extended answer.

Comment: If they're just going to hard code the version number, why can't they just put the number where they need it? Or add it as a constant if it needs to be referenced multiple places.

Comment: Well, sometimes you need to learn it the hard way ;-) I would also simply use a constant, but reading a file is more challenging.

Answer (score 0):

You can get at this info by running `xcodebuild -version` in terminal.
Following on from this, you can set up a **run script build phase** to query this and store the output in a file (say, your `appinfo.plist`) that you can query at runtime.

For an example of this, see [How this blogger adds git information into his app](http://rossfranklin.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/automatically-add-git-hash-to-infoplist.html)